# is this explicit linear operator hypo-elliptic

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, schwartz-distributions

Consider an operator of the form 
$$L(\phi):=\Delta \phi + \gamma \phi_{rr}$$  here the $r$ denotes derivative with respect to the radial variable (we are in $ R^N$ say  where $N \ge 3$).

I am curious whether I can apply some abstract results to $L$ that require $L$ to be hypo-elliptic (I kinda know what the word means but have absolutely zero experience).

My belief is this is not hypo-elliptic since I can use separation of variables (using spherical harmonics) to come up with a non smooth solution of $L(\phi)=0$  but there is a nonzero chance that I am screwing up the computation and really the equation is $ L(\phi)=\mu$ where $\mu$ some distribution supported at the origin.
thanks
Craig

Comment: What is $\gamma$? What does your solution look like when you convert it back to Cartesian coordinates?

Comment: If $\gamma<0$ then $L$ is (strictly) hyperbolic, therefore not hypo-elliptic. If $\gamma>0$ then $L$ is elliptic, in particular hypo-elliptic. Here, I assume that $\Delta$ is the traditional (negative) Laplacian.

Comment: So $ \Delta$ is the usual one (not the negative one) and I forgot to add $ \gamma>0$.  So it appears from the above comments its not hypo-elliptic.     Regarding what my solution looks like after putting it back to Cartesian (I am not sure.... I am a little clueless on doing things like this).  I have a more general question that I might start new thread on.

Comment: But I think i can clarify my confusion with a radial example.  If we consider the radial function $ \phi(x)= \frac{1}{|x|^\frac{N-2-\gamma}{1+\gamma}}$ for $ 0<\gamma<N-2$ this solves the pde (at least on the punctured space).  Since $\phi$ is better behaved than the fundamental solution of $\Delta$  then i assume it solves the pde on the full space in sense of distributions (but i guess i should attempt to check this).   So would this be sufficient to say the operator is not hypo-ellipitic?